# QML Rendering Engine: frame refresh event

Tags: c++, qt, qml

[Performance Considerations And Suggestions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html) article says:

> As an application developer, you must strive to allow the rendering
>   engine to achieve a consistent 60 frames-per-second refresh rate. 60
>   FPS means that there is approximately 16 milliseconds between each
>   frame in which processing can be done, which includes the processing
>   required to upload the draw primitives to the graphics hardware.

Is there an event or signal or any form of callback to make the code be called with that refresh?

The goal is to eliminate the need for handling the signal from the rendering thread in the UI thread slot. If the new data arrived then it will be drawn or marked for the next refresh to be drawn (with `update()` call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QQuickWindow` has a bunch of signals for the purpose of synchronization -  `beforeRendering()`, `afterRendering()`, `beforeSynchronizing()`, `afterSynchronizing()`, `frameSwapped()`. Take your pick.

Comment: I am writing the code for embedded device running in some QML context driven by the custom engine. That implies tweaking in that engine QML container window. Is there an entry through the nested QML type e.g. QQuickItem or likes?

Comment: There is no need to tweak anything, those signals exist and are emitted in the stock implementation. You just need to connect to them.

Comment: I can it is just a bit cumbersome from the code organization point of view. Need to reach for something. Good is that those signals from the same thread.

Comment: Given the QML design philosophy I'd say that the option to simply connect to and use those signals is very generous. There isn't anything to be desired in this aspect. I don't see how much easier you expect it to be.