# Get hold of milliseconds since unix epoch in QML at every frame

Tags: qt, timestamp, qml, shader, milliseconds

I need to pass the current time as *milliseconds since unix epoch* to a fragment shader in **QML**.

I noticed that there is a built in shader `uniform` var called `qt_Timestamp` in the [custom particle examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-particles-customparticle-example.html), but I never found out how to have that work in my own shader outside of that example.

I also tried using `(new Date).getTime()` in a snippet of javascript, I really need this to **run every frame**, and there seems to be no event or other way to have code run at every frame update.

So what is the proper way™ to do this?

Comment: M... I could have answered that but there "buts". My recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097090/qml-rendering-engine-frame-refresh-event So, you could have C++ part of your code emitting signal to QML but mind that not all events good for that and there implications with QML rendering loop as well. To me it is only getting called for each frame when I also set QML_BAD_GUI_RENDER_LOOP environment variable to make the rendering loop to be very regular at 60fps or 16ms. `connect(m_pQQWindow, &QQuickWindow::afterSynchronizing, this, &MyQmlItem::refreshInfo,Qt::DirectConnection);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097090/qml-rendering-engine-frame-refresh-event/43097174#43097174